# Example of using scalaz Monad

Tags: scala, monads, scalaz

Can anybody give an example of using scalaz [Monad](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/source/browse/trunk/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Monad.scala?spec=svn1397&r=1397) for a simple but non-trivial and practically useful task ?

Answer (score 16):

`scalaz.Monad`, and the family of related type classes, abstract some common functionality across a vast array of types. Scalaz provides general purpose functions that work for **any** `Monad`; and you can write your own functions in the same fashion.

Without this abstraction, you are forced to write these functions for each new monadic type that you encounter, e.g. `List`, `Parser`, `Option`. This gets tedious!

Here are examples of a few provided functions, working with a couple monadic types. My favorite is `sequence`:

```
scala> 1.pure[Option].pure[Option]
res1: Option[Option[Int]] = Some(Some(1))

scala> res1.join
res2: Option[Int] = Some(1)

scala> List(1.some, 2.some).sequence
res3: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(1, 2))

scala> List(1.some, none[Int]).sequence
res4: Option[List[Int]] = None

scala> List(1.pure[Function0])      
res5: List[() => Int] = List(<function0>)

scala> res5.sequence
res6: () => List[Int] = <function0>

scala> res6()
res7: List[Int] = List(1)

scala> true.some ifM(none[Int], 1.some)
res8: Option[Int] = None

scala> false.some ifM(none[Int], 1.some)
res9: Option[Int] = Some(1)
```